# Angular - customize built-in locales

Tags: angular, date, internationalization, locale, date-formatting

I have a problem with some built-in locales. For example, the italian one implements the short date format as dd/MM/yy which is incorrect speaking of birth dates (01/01/20, should be 1920 or 2020?).

I'd like to change that format to dd/MM/yyyy. I don't know if there's some built-in hook to do it, or have to work around.

I already started implementing my own solution, but don't want to lose the Angular i18n pipes...

Comment: Your question is not so clear, anyway you can use a Pipe Date in your template, like:

{{ myDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}

Here the docs: https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: I want to change the 'shortDate' format for some locales. For example the italian one from 'dd/MM/yy' to 'dd/MM/yyyy' without using a custom format. That's because I don't use it only in the Pipe Date, but also for other validations...